# Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, tsx

I have looked around a bit for a solution to this problem. All of them suggest adding `"jsx": "react"` to your tsconfig.json file. Which I have done. Another one was to add `"include: []"`, which I have also done. However, I am still getting the error when I am trying to edit `.tsx`files. Below is my tsconfig file.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "allowJs": true,
        "checkJs": false,
        "jsx": "react",
        "outDir": "./build",
        "rootDir": "./lib",
        "removeComments": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "pretty": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "strict": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "esModuleInterop": true
    },
    "include": [
        "./lib/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Any suggestions would be helpful. I am using babel 7 to compile all the code with the env, react and typescript presets. If you guys need more files to help debug this, let me know.

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. *babel 7 to compile all the code with the env, react and typescript presets* - why are there both Babel and TS and how are they related? *I am still getting the error* - which one? *"jsx": "react"* - [Note: The identifier React is hard-coded, so you must make React available with an uppercase R](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html)

Comment: I encountered the above error after creating the react app using the typescript template.

After going through the package.json, the section under script is auto-added when using the command "npx create-react-app you-project-name --template typescript". See below:
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },

Go to the project directory ("cd you-project-name").
Then to start the project, use/type "npm start"
To compile/build the project use/type "npm run build"

Answer (score 684, accepted):

> Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided

Restart your IDE. Sometimes tsconfig.json changes aren't immediately picked up.

Comment: The error remains on my machine. Looks like `"jsx": "react-jsx"` is not a valid value. I get the following error `Argument for '--jsx' option must be : 'preserve', 'react-native', 'react'.` But `create-react-app` sets it to `"react-jsx"`. What should I do?

Comment: You can also tell VS Code to use a specific version of TypeScript in a particular workspace by adding a typescript.tsdk workspace setting pointing to the directory of the tsserver.js file:

`"typescript.tsdk": "./node_modules/typescript/lib"`

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling#_using-newer-typescript-versions

Comment: Changing the version did the trick ! Take a look at the answer below :)

Comment: I changed tsconfig.json, and it worked,

  {
.....
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src",
    "/node_modules/**/*"
  ]
}.

Modified "jsx:react" and added "node_modules/**/*".

Comment: haha wow I thought surely there was some configuration issue and spent an extra 10 minutes trying to debug after reading this answer- but yep, this was it

Comment: without wasting the time got my answer... i think that the major reason you have to first try this solution..

Comment: You can also CMD/CTRL+SHIFT+P  > TypeScript: Restart TS Server to restart TS without restarting VSCode

Comment: No need to restart your VScode. cmd+shift+P and then "Reload Window"

Comment: Can't believe this was the missing step. Thanks.

Answer (score 885):

Every time I run `npm start`, it overrides whatever I configure in `{jsx: ...}` with `react-jsx` in order to be compatible with JSX transform in React 17.

```sh
The following changes are being made to your tsconfig.json file:
  - compilerOptions.jsx must be react-jsx (to support the new JSX transform in React 17)
```

The problem is VSCode using an older version of typescript (4.0.3), while the typescript version shipped with the project is (4.1.2).

The following did the trick for me:

1. Go to the command palette <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>   (Or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on Mac).
2. Choose "TypeScript: Select a TypeScript Version...".
3. Choose "Use workspace Version".

[image: VSCode status bar]

[image: VSCode command palette]

[image: TypeScript workspace version]

PS: This option doesn't show though unless you're on any .tsx file (thanks @awran5 for your comment and good catch)

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. This option doesn't show though unless you're on any `.tsx` file.

Comment: Yes, and in case your app is not in the top-level folder of your workspace you can configure the typescript directory as described at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling#_using-newer-typescript-versions

Comment: I don't even get the option to change the typescript version to the workspace version. I only get the VS Code version of 4.0.3, even though I have 4.1.2 installed.

Comment: This worked for my, just had to change `react-jsx` back to `react`.

Comment: Thanks! I was searching for an answer. Helped me a lot

Comment: I can confirm it works quite similar on WebStorm, thanks!

Comment: In PyCharm, you can check whether you are using an old TypeScript by looking at the language service version in `Settings > Languages > TypeScript`. Mine was coming from a `node_modules/typescript` from a different project with version 3.9.7. I pointed it to an updated TypeScript and it worked.

Comment: not work anymore.

Answer (score 256):

For whoever reading, go to the tsconfig.json and change that line from `react-jsx` to `react`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react"
  }
}
```

bonus: try also setting the IDE TS version to the latest (atm 4.2), in vscode CMD + SHIFT + P and change it from there.

Comment: unfortunately after you run `yarn start` or `npm start` it will return back to "react-jsx" :(

Comment: "jsx": "react" was missing from my tsconfig.  Added it and fixed the problem.

Comment: This is give me a [react umd global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64656055/react-refers-to-a-umd-global-but-the-current-file-is-a-module) error. One of the solution is putting back to `react-jsx`. I'm stucked in infinity loop of errors.

Comment: "jsx": "preserve" did work for me (I'm using babel and webpack along with)

Comment: this is missing the point, react-jsx is the **newer** transform. [That comes with a host of improvements](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html). so blanket, remove this, is hiding a lot of complexity

Comment: I also had to make the typscript dependency the latest version.

Answer (score 116):

`create-react-app` is broken out of the box. `AS OF 2022 MAY`

Inside of tsconfig, `include` was set only to `/src`, Change to:

```
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts"
  ]
```

Comment: Yeah I had the same setup also

Comment: I dont even get the option to change the typescript version to the workspace version. I only get the VS Code version of 4.0.3, even though I have 4.1.2 installed.

Comment: @Sapper6fd, yeah same. the creator of react-create-app talked about mismatch of vscode typescript and project typescript, might need to separately update vscode/its typescript?

Comment: and `.tsx` maybe?

Comment: I guess `create-react-app` is great starting point)

Answer (score 49):

In my case, the issue was that VSCode generated an empty `tsconfig.json` file which, of course, did nothing.

I added this to `tsconfig.json` from [Typescript's React Page](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/):

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "jsx": "react"
    }
}
```

...then hit `save` and VSCode took it from there.

**EDIT:**
Since I originally posted this answer generic `tsconfig` files have become more widely available.  I've posted a more expanded version as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/raydot/0853a8e968efeac6187f5e503f604527), if you'd like to understand the options.

Comment: How is this not upvoted more?!  This change fixed all the errors after running the audit fix that updated to expo@1.0.0.

Comment: Since I added that answer basic tsconfigs have become more widely available.  Here's one I've posted to github which explains the more widely used settings: <script src="https://gist.github.com/raydot/0853a8e968efeac6187f5e503f604527.js"></script>

Answer (score 26):

adding `"jsx": "react"` to jsconfig.json didn't work for me but  `"jsx": "preserve"` did:

jsconfig.json / tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "preserve"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had this issue on VStudio rather than actual compilation or running time

Answer (score 20):

April 2021, and this issue still persist. I am using [react-boilerplate-cra-template](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate-cra-template) with react 17.02.

This is an **issue with VSCode, it uses its in-built typescript by default**. You just need to open a .tsx file and

1. **Press:** Ctrl + Shift + P
2. **Enter:** Typescript: Select typescript version...
3. **Select:** Use workspace version.

Comment: this worked for like 5 seconds before it reverted back to the old version, still no solution on my end

Comment: This is [identical to the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64969461/542251)

Answer (score 14):

If you are seeing this issue after running create-react-app with Typescript You can solve this problem by adding `"typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib"` to `.vscode/settings.json`.

For IntelliSense, if you use `"jsx": "react-jsx"` you need to switch your workspace to use TS 4.1+

Or visually, simply go down to the blue task bar and select the Typescript version (Probably 4.x.x something), then select "Select TypeScript Version".

[image]

Then select "Use Workspace Version version" which should reference `node_modules/typescript/lib`

[image]

Comment: The preferable solution - change your IDE setting instead of changing your appplication! +1

Answer (score 14):

Restarting your IDE seems too brutal, and doesn't always work. You want to **Restart TS Server** instead:

[image: click settings - command palette]

[image: restart ts server]

*Note: the option will only show up if your IDE has any TS related file open*

Answer (score 9):

This answer is regarding VS Code and this particular error persisting in that IDE. (Someone may find this useful)

If you're using something like Webpack or some other such tooling you may still get this error even if your tsconfig has the compiler option for jsx set to React.

There is a solution to this. The problem is VS Code has built in auto detection for tsc.

To get rid of the error in the editor you can put this in your User Settings:

```
{
    "typescript.tsc.autoDetect": "off"
}
```

Just note that you will no longer get tsc auto detection but if you're primarily using tooling like Webpack or handling the command yourself with flags then this isn't that big of a deal.

Note: Only do this if the error is persisting in VS Code. To ensure this behavior is persisting reload the windows and restart the editor after configuring your tsconfig.json file.

Answer (score 9):

I got this same error when migrating my React app to use TypeScript. I resolved it by adding to my `tsconfig.json` the [jsx](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#jsx) compiler option with a value of `react-jsx`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  }
}
```

A popular answer above suggests using the `react` value instead, which *also* resolves the error:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "jsx": "react"
  }
}
```

But I have seen [various](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73518971/3368818) [sources](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/10/20/react-v17.html#new-jsx-transform) [that](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/using-create-react-app-v2-and-typescript#examining-the-tsconfig-json-file) seem to indicate the `react-jsx` option is preferable, so figured that approach is worth mentioning as well.

Not sure why neither of these options gets initially included in the `tsconfig.json` that gets generated when using the tsc init [option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html):

```
npx tsc --init
```

Comment: The reason these options are not included by default is because many TypeScript projects don't use JSX

Answer (score 6):

I was getting this error even when running `npx tsc --jsx preserve` so the `--jsx` was definitely specified.

In my case this was caused by having `incremental: true` in the tsconfig. Apparently in incremental mode `tsc` may ignore the `--jsx` setting, and use information from previous builds instead (where `--jsx` was still disabled). As a solution I turned of incremental compilation temporarily, recompiled, and re-enabled it. Probably deleting the build artifacts might also work.

Comment: That was my case. Your answer helped

Comment: `npx tsc ./src/index.ts --jsx react` ✅

Comment: `npx tsc ./src/index.ts --jsx='react'` ❌

Answer (score 5):

To solve this for all future projects, you can install `JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly` extension for VSCode.

Answer (score 5):

For those who use Visual Studio 2019, you can fix it by doing all following:

1. In tsconfig.json, have this part

```
"include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts"
]
```

2. Update Typescript sdk in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript`
   I had had version 4.0. I needed to update it to 4.1 (more clearly, 4.1.2) by

   1. deleting the Typescript folder
   2. In Visual Studio 2019, Extensions > Manage Extensions, install `Typescript 4.1 for Visual Studio`

Answer (score 4):

Restarting my IDE in my case was the fix.After restarting a message box popped up and it was showing that i don't have any typescript installed, would you like to install TypeScript 3.3? 
I installed it and now its working perfectly.[See here for output window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mqz5N.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

Restarting my IDE didn't help. Restarting the TypeScript server did resolve it tho.

Comment: restarting nvim solved it for me, which also restarted the tsserver lsp. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I my case none of the solutions were working, so I looked the version of ECMA Scrypt. My version was ec5, you can check here -> [tsconfig.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNKQk.png). So I tried to switch  the `target: "es5"`  to `target: "es2017"` an it seems to handle the problem, with anything comes up again, I'll edit this comment

Answer (score 4):

#### Solution for Sublime Text:

1. Make sure your package.json uses Typescript >= v4.1.2
2. Uninstall the Sublime Text "Typescript" package through Package Control

   - At time of writing, it bundles Typescript v3.x
3. Open a terminal in the Sublime Text "Packages" directory.

   - `cd "~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages"`
4. Clone the Typescript-Sublime-Plugin repo into your Packages directory:

   - `git clone https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Sublime-Plugin TypeScript`
5. Open User Settings: **`Sublime Text > Preferences > Settings`**
6. Add `"typescript_tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib"`

   - This tells the Sublime Typescript plugin to use the project version of Typescript rather than its bundled version.
7. Restart Sublime Text

   - Unlike most Sublime Text settings, this one requires a restart in order to restart the Typescript server.

*Reference:*
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Sublime-Plugin/issues/538

Comment: This was able to solve a problem I had with React 17 and using the `"jsx": "react-jsx"` problem.

Comment: Quick clarification for Windows 10 users, according to Microsoft's github README.md, step 4 must be run in the ```%APPDATA%\Sublime Text 3\Packages``` directory. An easy way to find where yours is is by navigating within Sublime Text 3 to: Preferences->Browse Packages.

Answer (score 3):

Adding
{
"compilerOptions": {
"jsx": "react"
}
}
to 'tsconfig.json' file and restarting the editor resolved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This link was helpful to resolve this issue:
https://staxmanade.com/2015/08/playing-with-typescript-and-jsx/

Refer the section:
Fixing error TS17004: Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided.

The next error is new to me, but it makes some sense, so I add the --jsx flag to tsc and try tsc --jsx helloWorld.tsx, but looks like I missed a parameter to --jsx.

> tsc --jsx helloWorld.tsx
>   message TS6081: Argument for '--jsx' must be 'preserve' or 'react'.
>   In the current iteration of TypeScript 1.6 appears to have two options for --jsx, both preserve or react.

preserve will keep the jsx in the output. I presume this is so you can use tools like JSX to actually provide the translation.
react will remove the jsx syntax and turn it in to plain javascript so  in the TSX file would become React.createElement("div", null).
By passing the react option, here's where we end up:

> tsc --jsx react helloWorld.tsx
>   helloWorld.tsx(11,14): error TS2607: JSX element class does not support attributes because it does not have a 'props' property
>   helloWorld.tsx(11,44): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'mountNode'.
>   I'm going to tackle the last error next, as initially I didn't understand the JSX error above.

Comment: usually my tsconfig would change on yarn start but it did not this time. adding uncommenting "jsx":"preserve" in tsconfig.json worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I got this same error, and just figured out how to resolve it. The problem was that there was a `jsconfig.json` file which caused the TypeScript compiler to ignore the `tsconfig.json` file.

To determine if you have the same problem, in your IDE (I'm using VS Code), load a file which has the error in your editor, then bring up the Command Palette and enter "TypeScript: Go to Project Configuration". If it opens up `jsconfig.json`, then delete that file and restart your IDE. If it opens the `tsconfig.json` file this time, you are golden.

Answer (score 2):

I had to add my whole app into `include`.

So my tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "include": ["./"]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just fixed this problem with a bud of mine who was reinstalling and reconfiguring every damn thing to fix it. We tried every fix on the internet (I even had to solve this myself, so I was really confused why we could fix it for him).

The problem turned out to be this [TypeScript God](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=basarat.god) extension. Once it was disabled, and subsequently removed, the issue was solved.

Beware the False God!

Comment: The link throws 404

Comment: @trainoasis It must have been removed.

Answer (score 2):

I have a monorepo and for me Webstorm automagically had chosen an older version of TypeScript for a sub-package. The fix was clicking on TypeScript X.X.X in the footer and choose `Configure TypeScript ...` and choose the right package, that worked for me in Webstorm 2021.1

Comment: I appreciate that someone went ahead and posted a solution for Intellij

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I tried all the `tsconfig.json`, Project Properties dialog, restarting IDE, checking installed TypeScript version, etc, and it still had this error. Come to find out the dev that made the project added conditional properties to the project file, such that `TypeScriptJSXEmit` is not defined in all configurations (which confused the Project Properties dialog).

Here's an excerpt from my project file showing the issue:

```
...
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'QA'">
    <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
    <TypeScriptJSXEmit>React</TypeScriptJSXEmit>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, none of the above did work.
My problem was that the location of tsconfig.json was not the project root.
So that jest could not read .jsx files.
I solved it just symlink tsconfig.json to the project root.
There might be better solution.
Let me know if you have one.

Answer (score 1):

The below error I am getting after running **yarn start**:

```
> multi-step-form-typescript@0.1.0 start /home/ehsan/Documents/GitHub/multi-step-form-typescript
> react-scripts start

/home/ehsan/Documents/GitHub/multi-step-form-typescript/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/utils/verifyTypeScriptSetup.js:239
      appTsConfig.compilerOptions[option] = value;
                                          ^

TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'jsx' of object '#<Object>'
    at verifyTypeScriptSetup (/home/ehsan/Documents/GitHub/multi-step-form-typescript/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/utils/verifyTypeScriptSetup.js:239:43)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ehsan/Documents/GitHub/multi-step-form-typescript/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:31:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! multi-step-form-typescript@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the multi-step-form-typescript@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ehsan/.npm/_logs/2020-11-22T18_20_20_546Z-debug.log
```

So what you need to do in order to get rid of this

on your terminal click on the error link

**/home/ehsan/Documents/GitHub/multi-step-form-typescript/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/utils/verifyTypeScriptSetup.js:239**
appTsConfig.compilerOptions[option] = value;

and then change the 239 lines to

**else if (parsedCompilerOptions[option] !== valueToCheck && option !== "jsx")**

Now after changing this goto tsconfig.json

and than replace **"jsx": "react-jsx"** to **"jsx": "react"**

now run your project with **sudo yarn start**

It's work for me, hope this will work for you too :)

Answer (score 1):

I followed the "Simpler Solution" mentioned here https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10144#issuecomment-733278351

"...update the TS version in package.json to 4.1.2"

and then restarted VS Code.

Simply restarting the TS server with the command palette didn't do it for me.

I didn't need any other steps.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, restarting VSCode and upgrading typescript and run-scripts to the matching versions were not enough. Rebuilding after deleting the .eslintcache file finally resolved the error.

Answer (score 1):

#### My Experience

I was converting an existing newly created NextJS App to use TS following the [official next guide](https://nextjs.org/learn/excel/typescript) and when i reached to the part where the pages/_app.tsx needed to be modified.

I followed the VSCode prompt to add --jsx flag, which added the following lines to the next.config.js file:

```js
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: all,
};
```

which resulted in another error:

```
Failed to load next.config.js, see more info here https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-config-error
ReferenceError: all is not defined
```

Upon removing the lines from the next.config.js file and restarting VSCode and rerunning `yarn dev` or `npm run dev` and Voila! It started working!

Answer (score 0):

This is a follow-up fo the answer by @basarat, because he partially solved the issues in my case. The problem I was having was `error TS6046: Argument for '--jsx' option must be: 'preserve', 'react-native', 'react'`. I solved it as follows:

1. **Restart** your IDE
2. **Delete** your tsconfig.json
3. **Re-initialise** your tsconfig.json using ```tsc --init````

Maybe step one could be skipped, but I did not investigate this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a .vscode/settings.json file at the root of you project. In it type `{ "typescript.tsdk": "node_modules\\typescript\\lib" }` you're good to go.

The issue is that vscode is using an old Typescript version.

[image showing code on vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPTQr.png)

Answer (score -1):

Just simply replace your tsconfig.json with this script

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

and you will be all good

Cheers

Answer (score -2):

You can install the npm packages again with the **npm install** comment. It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).