# VSCode not picking up jsx when tsconfig is extended

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, jsx

I've got a monorepo project structured in the following way

```
/web
/native
  /tsconfig.json
tsconfig.json
```

My `/native/tsconfig.json` looks like this

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-native"
  }
}
```

But for some reason my `.tsx` files with some jsx in them return following error

> [ts] Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided. [17004]

When I typecheck using cli tsc, I don't get these errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50432556/cannot-use-jsx-unless-the-jsx-flag-is-provided)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the folder like this in your `tsconfig`.

```
"include": [
  "./src/ts/**/*" //Path to your source
],
"jsx": "preserve",
```

Answer (score 2):

Typescript version in VsCode workspace and package.json are not equal.
To solve this problem in Vscode,

1. Open the tsx file. In right bottom corner you will find [image: typescript react]

2 click this button and choose  change VS Code to use the workspace's version of Typescript.

The errors will disappear.