# Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided when "jsx" is "react-jsx"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, react-scripts

typescript throws:

> Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided.ts(17004)

After changing `tsconfig.json` `jsx` to `react-jsx`, jsx works. `yarn start` changes tsconfig.json to `react-jsx` again.

`react-scripts` was updated to 4.0.1.

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.9",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.8.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.8.1",
    "eslint-config-react": "^1.1.7",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2"
  },
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50432556/cannot-use-jsx-unless-the-jsx-flag-is-provided?rq=1

Comment: No. Restarting VSCode does not solve this problem, because react-scripts will change tsconfig.json `jsx` to `react-jsx` which will end in typescript throwing an error.

Comment: @FelHa You can post your found solution as answer, no question update needed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can fix this the [following way](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10107):

> "Ctrl + Shift + P" or Click Typescript version at the bottom right of
> the window. TypeScript: Select TypeScript Version Use Workspace
> Version... 4.1.2"

Comment: Note: this will add `{ "typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib" }` to your settings.json. You can add this to your global `settings.json` if you experience this issue for multiple projects

Comment: How does changing VSCode settings which should be unrelated to yarn start command from terminal solve the issue? I am just curious here

Answer (score 4):

This is due to a new bug, it's a mismatch between vscode and typescript. If the other solutions won't work; I changed `include: "src"` inside `tsconfig.json` to

```
"include": [
     "./src/**/*.ts"
]
```

Comment: This worked for me in VisualStudio2022