# I cannot find what the problem is about create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

all of sudden, I encountered something I cannot handle

when I do "create-react-app" and want to compile something,

it takes too.... much time to compile

most weirdly, it is only occurred when I change "components"

like typing "too slow " and after save it,

compiling takes too much time.

changing css is not the case of it. it is immediately complied and applied

only components changing has problem of compile speed.

I tried html file with live server, but it is compiled very fast.

so I think create-react-app has something wrong but I cannot understand of it

+

recently when I use "npx create-react-app . --template typescript" ,

when I do "npm run start" it changes tsconfig and makes lots of error about

"jsx" system

what's wrong with it. can anyone help me about my problem?

Comment: Maybe rebooting your machine can work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are having the problem of VSCode warns about the `--jsx` flag inside the `tsconfig.json`, that can be seen [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10139).

You can fix like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50432556/cannot-use-jsx-unless-the-jsx-flag-is-provided/64969461#64969461).

P.S: It would be very cool if the next time asking questions, you could format and proofread so that what you write is easier to understand.