# Create React App shows "Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided"

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm struggling with following error in React app with typescript:

```
Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided
```

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50432556/cannot-use-jsx-unless-the-jsx-flag-is-provided

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50432556/cannot-use-jsx-unless-the-jsx-flag-is-provided)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your `tsconfig.json` file:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "jsx": "react"
 },
```