# NeoVim for TypeScript React development

Tags: reactjs, typescript, neovim

I am new to vim. I just wanted to check out my configuration with react and since I use typescript with react I tried creating a simple demo app so I ran `npx create-react-app demo --template typescript`.
Afterward, I ran `nvim .` inside the directory, but when I selected any of the components, I get this warning:

> Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided. (FixIt)

[image: warning preview]

even though it is specified in the tsconfig.json file

tsconfig.json file:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

I did install a TS plugin and I have no idea why this happens

This is my vim config so far [ez-config](https://github.com/EtshD1/ez-config/blob/main/.vimrc), and I used the `:help nvim-from-vim` to let nvim load config from the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having is with this line --> "jsx":"react-jsx", it has to be changed to "jsx":"react", however, every time you run npm it will probably override it to "react-jsx". You can try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64969461/14944117

Comment: Thank you, I never thought that would be the issue because VS Code works with it.