# Enabling JSX Support in Vue after deliberately not supporting it during installation

Tags: vue.js, jsx, vuejs3

Basically the title.

I had deliberately not enabled JSX support during initialization of a new Vue Project. Is there a way to enable JSX support. I get these type of warnings:

[image]

They don't effect while serving but still i think what i did was a mistake.
Is their a way to enable JSX support now? Or will I have to initialize the project once again?

Comment: But your code is not of JSX syntax

Comment: I know, but why is then the error mentioning JSX syntax? (does not have any construct or call signatures)

Comment: I think you're enabling some extension, try to install the volar extension

Comment: @Vivek I cannot reproduce the issue in a newly scaffolded project via `create-vue`. What steps did take you create this project? Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a common problem in React too. Maybe its related enabling JSX support during installation ? I don't know. As [@tony19](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6277151/tony19) said he also installed disbaling JSX support and still didn't get any errors.

We can solve this issue by adding the following code in our `jsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "preserve"
  }
}
```

For further reference refer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72332435/14064881